# Internet explorer save new windows in global variable

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Hi i would like to open a new window to log automatic user and when he is log (the domain name will change) close the windows so i set an interval to analyse the url but in internet explorer in the interval function the new windows is a empty object,

> [object Object]
>      { }
>   i tried a lot of things to do it but that does not work

```
        window.someOtherVariableName = '';
        function fnStartClock(){
         oInterval = setInterval(fnDoClock,2000);
        }
        function fnDoClock(){
            if (window.someOtherVariableName == '')
            {
                window.someOtherVariableName = window.open('','','height=1,width=1'); ; 
                window.someOtherVariableName.location.assign(myurl);
            }
           console.log(window.someOtherVariableName.location);
        }

        window.onload = fnStartClock; 


        console.log(window.someOtherVariableName);
```

i tried with a window.someOtherVariableName var , with a 'var newwindows = ..' but that never work

i get the object only in the first console.log

Comment: `location.assign`?  Why not `location.href`? Why not directly remove this line and make the `window.open('http://your-location')` ?

Comment: Isn't this going to get slapped down by the restrictions on popup window opening?

Comment: [Internet Explorer seems to return null if the url is outside your current domain.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827616/javascript-window-open-returns-null-in-32-bit-ie8-on-win7-x64)

Comment: @Quentin no the window is open (i accepted the add for this domain)    this code work on chrome

Comment: after the window.someOtherVariableName.location.assign(myurl); the someOtherVariableName var is an empty object